# Authenticating large file uploads

Tags: post, node.js, restful-authentication, express

I'm implementing an API that must accept fairly large file uploads. The request will contain email and password parameters for authentication. Is it reasonable to force developers to place the email and password parameters /before/ the file data?

I'm using Formidable (a Node module) to parse the body and I figured that if I could pick out the email and password (and attempt to authenticate) before accepting the entire file, I could save memory and processor cycles by closing the connection before all the data streams in. Should I even worry about this?

I can certainly write the data to a temporary directory and either delete or move it based on the authentication attempt, but I'd like to find a better way, if one exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say yes, it's OK to insist that someone proves who he/she is (and so forth) before accepting a large amount of data from him/her.